# Why does this function not increment the timeout?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why this script doesn't increment the timeout by `i`, which is what I'd expect it to do:

```
for( var i=0; i<10; i++ ){
    setTimeout( function(){
        console.log( i );
    }, i*10 );
}
```

This just logs `10`, ten times. `setTimeout` should have access to `i`, as should the function, from what I can tell. Still, it doesn't work as I expect it to.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnj6nsLb/)

Comment: Because in the moment that `console.log` is called, the value of `i` is 10.

Comment: Check out JS Closures

Comment: Closures, my friend... closures ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that by the time the inner function gets executed, the value of `i` is 10, that's why you're getting 10, 10 times.

Closures 'close' over variables not over values. This means that the closure (the function inside the `setTimeout`) has access to the **variable** at the time it executes no to the *value* of the variable when the closure was created.

So effectively you are executing the following code:

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<10; i++ ){
}

// delay 0ms
console.log(i);
// some delay 
console.log(i);
// some delay 

....
```

Also remember that JS is a single threaded language, so the first `setTimeout` can't execute until you "yield", that means that the first function inside the `setTimeout` only executes when the for loop finishes, it doesn't matter how small a delay you specify in the `setTimeout`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to accept this, but "*Closures 'close' over variables not over values.*" is very vague to me. Could you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: Also, is this not also partially a race condition? I've read that the minimum `setTimeout` delay is 4ms (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Notes). Does this mean that the for loop finishes within 4ms, and thereby sets `i = 10` for all exexuted code?

Comment: see edits for both comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand about closure. Here's the solution to your problem:

```
for( var i=0; i<10; i++ ){
  (function(i){
    setTimeout( function(){
        console.log( i );
    }, i*10 );
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: *"You need to understand about closure."* Are you going to help the OP understand?

Comment: There's this thing called "Google".

Comment: @Hoyen That's not really a valid answer on stack overflow though. Otherwise you could answer all questions with RTFM.